# The additive Chernoff bound for the absolute value.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds, moment-generating-functions, distribution-tails

I am trying to derive a generic, additive Chernoff bound for $\Pr[|X-\mu|\leq a]$ with $a>0$. By generic I mean a Chernoff bound in terms of the moment generating function instead of assuming a specific distribution of $X$.

Applying the Markov inequality gives the upper tail:

$$\Pr[X-\mu\geq a] = \Pr[X\geq \mu + a]\leq \frac{E[e^{Xt}]}{e^{(\mu + a)t}}$$

and the lower tail

$$\Pr[X-\mu \leq - a] = \Pr[X\leq \mu - a]\leq \frac{E[e^{-Xt}]}{e^{-(\mu - a)t}}$$

I am not sure how to combine these two to obtain a bound for $\Pr[|X-\mu|\leq a]$.

I could not find such generic bound in online resources. Only for $X$ following a Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the complement event. For instance, we can use the union bound as follows:

$$
\mathrm{P}(|X-\mu|\geq a) = \mathrm{P}(\{X-\mu\geq a\} \cup \{X-\mu\leq -a\} )\leq \mathrm{P}(X-\mu\geq a)+ \mathrm{P}(X-\mu\leq -a).
$$
This is a generic approach and you may use other tricks for particular problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mahdi, but my question asks for a bound on $P(|X-\mu|\leq a)$, not $P(|X-\mu|\geq a)$. Following the same logic,  $P(|X-\mu|\leq a) = P(\{X-\mu\leq a\} \cap \{X-\mu\geq - a\}) $, but then I can't apply the union bound.

Comment: I know. but you can say then $P(|X-\mu|< a)=1- P(|X-\mu| \geq a)\geq 1- \mathrm{P}(X-\mu\geq a) - \mathrm{P}(X-\mu\leq -a) $.

and you can use your upper bounds .

Comment: maybe I am missing your question but in the usual concentration bounds we try first to control the probability that the random variable is "not" concentrated.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!